# Anaconda Installation: ungtz.dll error

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install Anaconda using the normal python 3.5 windows 64-bit .exe file. Every time I run the installation, all the extraction in it fails due to error of some ungtz.dll file as shown in the picture. Even my Antivirus detects that file as a Trojan and repairs it.So after the installation ends there is not Anaconda Prompt and other such software.

[Anaconda Installation Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yag22.jpg)

Can anyone help and suggest how I go about successfully installing anaconda?

Comment: I would first try to disable the antivirus during installation

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Firewall and antivirus and try with run Administrator,or others versions